# Awk not displaying columns as expected

Tags: bash, macos, awk

I have a input file in the following format:

```
userA 3 5
userB 2 1
userC 1 3
userD 4 2
userE 5 4
```

I am trying to sort the file by the second number column and pretty print the output so it looks something like this:

```
Player    Current    Previous
------    -------    --------
userC     1          3
userB     2          1
userA     3          5
userD     4          2
userE     5          4
```

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

sort -k2 -n file.txt | head -n5 | \
awk 'BEGIN { print "Name  Current  Previous" 
     print "----  -------  --------" }
     { printf "%-10s %s\n", $1,$2,$3 }' | \
column -t
```

However this displays the output without displaying the 3rd column of numbers:

```
Player    Current    Previous
------    -------    --------
userC     1          
userB     2          
userA     3          
userD     4          
userE     5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your *printf* format string is missing the third *%s*, try to modify it like that:

```
printf "%-10s %-10s %s\n", $1,$2,$3
```